# AWK variables (1 in quotes)+ conditional

Tags: awk

I've followed a lot of `awk -v a=$var1 ..'BEGIN{...` posts online but it still won't work.

Here are the details:

In a terminal, I can subset a `.gtf` file as expected. Taken from [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/141968/#142129):

`awk '{if($1=="chr22" && $4>21799011 && $5<21807847 && $3=="exon") print $0}' GRCh38.gtf`

Which works as expected.

However when looping over a file to execute this there is no output:

```
while read line; do

        # stage coordinates to pull gtf info
        chr_tmp=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
        chr=$(echo $chr_tmp | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/') # echo prints "chr22"
        st=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
        sp_tmp=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
        sp=$(($sp_tmp + 1))
        name=$(echo $line | awk '{print $5}')
        
        awk -v chr="$chr" -v st="$st" -v sp="$sp" 'BEGIN {if($1==chr && $4>st && $5<sp && $3=="exon") print $0}' GRCh38.gtf > ${name}.gtf

done < circ.bed
```

This is strange as in a shell when I manually assign the variables, awk prints them as expected:

```
barry@NUIG:~/Desktop/BED12$ echo $chr
"chr22"
barry@NUIG:~/Desktop/BED12$ echo $st
21799011
barry@NUIG:~/Desktop/BED12$ echo $sp
21807846
barry@NUIG:~/Desktop/BED12$ awk -v chr="$chr" -v st="$st" -v sp="$sp" 'BEGIN {print chr, st, sp}'
"chr22" 21799011 21807846
```

But will not work outside of the script either:

```
awk -v chr="$chr" -v st="$st" -v sp="$sp" 'BEGIN{if($1==chr && $4 > st && $5 < sp) print $0}' GRCh38.gtf
```

There is no output when placing these in the awk command. Perhaps the fact `$1=="chr22"` must be in quotes is throwing awk off? Have also tried without double quotes on the `-v chr=$chr`, removing `BEGIN` to no avail.

Comment: Note that gtf is a tab-separated format and fields can contain spaces. You always want to do `awk -F"\t"` to be sure you're getting the right fields.

Comment: See also: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: Also, are the chromosome names really quoted in your `GRCh38.gtf` file?

Comment: @terdon you had the right idea, using `"chr22"` was not working. I interpreted the working example a bit too literally when assigning variables. `chr22` as the `$chr` variable worked.

Comment: Just so you know, you are reinventing the wheel here. `bedtools intersect` will do exactly what you want: it will return the entries of a GTF file that overlap with a bed file. You can then trivially filter for `exon`. Have a look at https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. This will be easier, simpler, and orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @terdon ah jaysus I wasn't thinking at all. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in `awk`, the variables `$1`, `$2`, and so on, refer to the values of detected fields (i. e. `$1` is the first field) in each record.

The `BEGIN` and `END` code blocks run before and after any data are read in to be parsed respectively.

In the `BEGIN` code block, no data have yet been read in, so none of the field variables will be populated, so all of your equality checks will fail.

Looking at your two tests:

```
$ awk -v chr="$chr" -v st="$st" -v sp="$sp" 'BEGIN {print chr, st, sp}'
"chr22" 21799011 21807846
```

Here you are setting `awk` variables equal to your shell variables, and printing those values.  All is well.

```
$ awk -v chr="$chr" -v st="$st" -v sp="$sp" 'BEGIN{if($1==chr && $4 > st && $5 < sp) print $0}' GRCh38.gtf
```

Here you have no code block running on the data it's reading in from the `.gtf` file- it's only doing the comparison to the fields in the `BEGIN` block, before any data are read in.

You probably want to do this:

```
$ awk -v chr="$chr" -v st="$st" -v sp="$sp" '{if($1==chr && $4 > st && $5 < sp) print $0}' GRCh38.gtf
```

This will run the checks and print data for each line in the file, as the checks and `print` statement are no longer in a `BEGIN` block.

I would also pull the checks outside of the run block, and make it process (in this case, print) the line only if the checks are valid:

```
$ awk -v chr="$chr" -v st="$st" -v sp="$sp" '$1==chr && $4 > st && $5 < sp {print $0}' GRCh38.gtf
```

Comment: Perhaps also significant is that `echo $chr` apparently produces (quoted) `"chr22"` whereas the original (working) conditional was `$1=="chr22"` not `$1=="\"chr22\""`

Comment: That may be a factor, but is secondary to doing the tests on actual data rather than on testing what is known to be null due to not having actually looked at any of them.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response @DopeGhoti, assigning `$chr` as `"chr22"` was the mistake as @steeldriver suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the responses. Sorry I am too low on rep to upvote you all.

`awk -v chr="$chr" -v st="$st" -v sp="$sp" '$1==chr && $4 > st && $5 < sp {print $0}' GRCh38.gtf`

&

`awk -v chr="$chr" -v st="$st" -v sp="$sp" '{if($1==chr && $4 > st && $5 < sp) print $0}' GRCh38.gtf`

Worked.

My mistake (along with using `BEGIN`) in the script was thinking awk wanted the `chr` variable in quotes because in a terminal while this line works:

`awk '{if($1=="chr22" && $4>21799011 && $5<21807847 && $3=="exon") print $0}' GRCh38.gtf`

This one does not:

`awk '{if($1==chr22 && $4>21799011 && $5<21807847 && $3=="exon") print $0}' GRCh38.gtf`

Comment: As [@DopeGhoti pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613577/awk-variables-1-in-quotes-conditional#comment1145921_613579), the quotes were only the *secondary* reason your original command failed - the primary reason was placing the conditional inside a `BEGIN` block.